# Why can we factorize the state of a particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I read about factorization in these two cases:

1. When spin and position are not coupled it is
   possible to factorize the state in a wave function and a spinor $|\psi\rangle|\chi\rangle$
2. If there are two independent particles, it is possible to write the wave function as a product of wave functions  $\psi(\vec x_a) \psi(\vec x_b)$

I don't understand the logic behind it, is it a math property or a quantum axiom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the factorizability  is an axiom. Formally, it is states as

> The Hilbert space of a composite system is the Hilbert space tensor product of the state spaces associated with the component systems (for instance, J. M. Jauch, Foundations of quantum mechanics, section 11.7). For a non-relativistic system consisting of a finite number of distinguishable particles, the component systems are the individual particles. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Postulates_of_quantum_mechanics)

It can be essentially paraphrased as

**When we want to combine degrees of freedom we take their tensor product $\otimes$ of their corresponding spaces.**

Why? It comes down to the Linear Algebra formalism. Suppose a hamiltonian looks like

$$H = H_{spatial} + H_{spin}$$

Well... kind of. This way of writing it is mathematically imprecise. Really the hamiltonian $H$ lives in the hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{pos} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{spin}$ (since we are combining degrees of freedom), and so the correct way of writing it is

$$ H = H_{spatial} \otimes \mathbf{1}_{spin} + \mathbf{1}_{pos} \otimes H_{spin} $$

which jives with the above postulate.

---

Edit: As Dan Yand pointed out in the comments, it is important to note that my answer refers to the axiom of the factorizability of the **Hilbert spaces**, not to the factorizability of a particular **state**. In general one cannot always do the latter.

Comment: So for example (neglecting the spin)  if I have a system of 2 identical particles the states live in the Hilbert space H1⊗H2 but their wave functions can not be factorized because of the symmetry requirement? Instead if the particles are distinguishable I can factorize the state in a tensor product of a function that lives in H1 and another that lives in H2?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an axiom but a mathematical property. In general a two particle state is the function of the two particles. Only in the special case that the two particles are *uncorrelated*, such a function can be written as a product of two one-particle wave functions. Multi-particle states of identical quantum particles can in general not be written as products. For example, many-electron states have to be written as (expansions of) Slater determinant functions.
As to factorization into a spatial and a spin orbital, this is possible only if the spin is not correlated to the spatial coordinates.